# Parsing tweets' text out of "Status" wrapper in json file

Tags: python, tweepy

I used this tweepy-based [code](https://gist.github.com/yanofsky/5436496) to pull the tweets of a given user by user_id. I then saved a list of all tweets of a given user (alltweets) to a json file as follows. Note that without "repr", i wasn't able to dump the alltweets list into json file. The code worked as expected

```
with open(os.path.join(output_file_path,'%s_tweets.json' % user_id), 'a') as f:
     json.dump(repr(alltweets), f)
```

However, I have a side problem with retrieving the tweets after saving them to the json file. I need to access the text in each tweet, but I'm not sure how to deal with the "Status" wrapper that tweepy uses (See a sample of the json file attached).[sample json file content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmzdQ.png)

I tried to iterate over the lines in the file as follows, but the file is being seen as a single line.

```
with open(fname, 'r') as f: 
     for line in f: 
        tweet = json.loads(line)
```

I also tried to iterate over statuses after reading the json file as a string, as follows, but iteration rather takes place on the individual characters in the json file.

```
with open(fname, 'r') as f: 
     x = f.read() 
          for status in x: 
               """code"""
```

Comment: Please state a clear question. I don't see any question mark, and it is not clear at the moment what exactly you or asking...

Comment: You are not saving json in your file. You're actually saving a `repr` of list of `Status` objects. You need to get the json out of the objects before saving.

Comment: @JulienBernu: My question is, how can I iterate over the many Statuses in the json file and extract the tweets' 'text'?

Comment: @Sevanteri yes, in agreement with what you said, Tweepy docs process the Satuses first thing after streaming them. Unfortunately it was too late when i learned that. Right now, I have 100G of twitter data that I saved as repr of list that I need to process. So, as in my reply above, the question is how can I iterate over the many Statuses in the json file and extract the tweets' 'text'?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the prettiest solution but you could just declare `Status` as a `dict` and then `eval` the list (the whole content of the files).

```
Status = dict

f = open(fname, 'r')
data = eval(f.read())
f.close()

for status in data:
    """ do your stuff"""
```